# How to remove Documents from Navigation Pane

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do you remove 'Documents' from the Navigation Pane in File Explorer?

[image]

I have found solutions for removing -

- [Network](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4854-add-remove-network-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)
- [Dropbox](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/59830-add-remove-dropbox-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)
- [Libraries](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4222-hide-show-libraries-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)
- [OneDrive](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/remove-onedrive-file-explorer-sidebar-windows-10/)

**Version Listings**

Here is how each version is listed in File Explorer -

[image]  [image]

Can 'Documents' be removed from the Navigation Pane as well, from root like seen here?

**Registry Listings**

- [CLSID](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adzctdtfqrfzche/clsid.reg?dl=0) ([xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6alpuhxbmr63vw7/clsid_flat.xls?dl=0))
- [pin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm0i2q1tqfpbul0/pin.reg?dl=0)

Comment: Good findings! Probable solution; Right click on the real Documents folder (C:\Users\name\Documents). Choose unpin from quick access.

Comment: @Biswapriyo   your suggestion removes 'Quick Access\Documents', how can you get the root version shown in pic, e.g. 'Documents\'?

Comment: How did you put that in navigation pane? That icon is generally present under "This PC" or "Quick Access".

Comment: that's what I thought! Never intentionally added it

Comment: lol, a Google Search for images of "Windows File Explorer" never shows 'Documents' at root like I have now - should I file a formal Microsoft Q?

Comment: Google System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree this is the registry setting for each related CLSID that is pinned to the navigation pane.

Comment: @J-Dizzle Idea! Open this app https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html and search for "Documents" and find a regeity path containing "CLSID". I don't find anything.

Comment: @Biswapriyo lol Nirsoft FTW, as usual. Will explore here tmrw and review @Appleoddity’s suggestion and post results. Fun stuff here!

Comment: I used RegScanner to retrieve reg listings for 'CLSID' and 'pin' see "Registry Listings" section above. No luck! Thoughts?